# New to webservice dev, having issues with web.py + wsdl

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, web.py

I am new to web-service development but have been learning python and wanted to try my hand at a project. I was able to get a simple site up and running using web.py

Now that I have this going I am trying to raising the complexity from basically just a website that makes simple decisions based on input into something more advanced.

Part of this is to get proper SOAP and WSDL

I was trying to use this tutorial : http://webpy.org/cookbook/webservice

but soaplib seems to be defunct. I found an old copy of it but couldn't get that off the ground, so I suspect I need to migrate to a different lib. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking for something that works with web.py I don't know, but webservice frameworks in python: django rest framework (I think does not support soap, but everybody is using rest nowadays), spyne, zato that I know. Maybe they are a bit overkill.

Comment: Thanks @dyeray for your comment. Based on the research I have been doing since posting this questions, I think I may not bother with SOAP and will stick to a simple REST + JSON interface.... Thanks again, all the best -David